# recurrence relation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can I build a recurrence equation if there isn't an $n$-variable?  Example: $a_n = 3$.  Also, how would I start making a recurrence equation for $a_n = 2n + 3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, you could use $a_0=3$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}$. For the second, put $a_0=3$ and $a_n=2+a_{n-1}$.

Ultimately, we need to determine what the relationship between subsequent terms is. In the first case, there is *no difference at all* (hence the $a_n=a_{n-1}$ bit). For the second, we note that each term will be $2$ more than the previous one (hence the $a_n=2+a_{n-1}$ bit). But that isn't enough. We also need to figure out what (at least) one $a_n$ is for these cases, or our recurrence relation suggests an infinite family of sequences, rather than a specific closed form. Fortunately, this part is easily done ("plug in" whatever $n$ you like).

What do you notice about the relationship between the subsequent terms of $a_n=3^n\cdot 5$? What about $a_n=1+n^2$? (The latter is tricker.)

Comment: I don't understand why you chose $a_0=3$.  Will you explain?

Comment: Does my expanded answer clear things up?

Comment: Re-reading your post.  Thank you for the edits.  I see now that since $a_n = CONSTANT$ regardless of the index, it is equal to the value at the previous index.

Comment: Exactly right! P.S.: if you want to put multiple things in a subscript, then `$base_{subscript}$` yields $base_{subscript}$. Same thing works for superscripts.

Comment: For $a_n = 3^n * 5$ I notice that the subsequent term will be 5 times the previous term, and $log_3$ x = n...  But, I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: What exactly is $x$ in $\log_3x=n$? Have you tried putting a few values in for $n$? $a_0=5,$ $a_1=15,$ $a_2=45,$ $a_3=135.$ Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I appreciate your help.  So, I think this is where I'm stuck.  For example, on this problem:  1) $a_n = 2^n$ so $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 4$.  Now that I've tried a few terms, am I supposed to figure out an equation to recursively find the prior term to $a_n$?

Comment: Now that you've tried a few terms, do you see a pattern emerging that suggest a rule to get from one term to the next?

Comment: Ahh, $a_n = 2a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Is there a way to solve these without plugging in numbers?  Or is that a key part of developing a recursive equation?

Comment: Indeed, $a_n=2a_{n-1}$! Plugging in numbers is often a good place to start, if the pattern isn't immediately clear to you.

Comment: I got it!  So: $a_n = 3^n * 5$ is recursively $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Good work.

Comment: For $a_n = 1 + n^2$ I see that the difference is increasing by the consecutive odd numbers... that's where I'm stuck.  Let me try to wrap my brain around it..

Comment: Exactly right. Play with it and see if you can express that explicitly.

Comment: OH MY GOD!  It's $a_n = a_{n-1} + n + (n-1)$, right?!

Comment: You're right! Though it's more simply expressed as $a_n=a_{n-1}+2n-1.$ Nice work. ^_^

Comment: Thank you!  Now I can finish my homework. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy hunting (of understanding)!

Comment: Another problem, another question... If you're still here.  What does "find the solution to this recurrence relation with the given initial condition.  Use an iterative approach."  What is the problem asking for?  The equation is: $a_n = -a_{n-1}, a_0 = 5$.  I see that it's just 5,-5,5,-5,5,-5....

Comment: This problem is asking you to go the *other* way, and find the closed form of the sequence. That is, they want you to express $a_n$ as a function of $n$.

Comment: Alright, so, here is an example problem that I am struggling with:  $a_n = a_{n-1} + 3$    ----- I see that $a_n = a_{n-1} + 3 = (a_{n-2}+3) + 3 = a_{n-2}+6$.... I don't know where to go from here..   Edit: Initial condition is $a_1 = 2$

Comment: Well, you're going the wrong direction (arguably). Given $a_1=2,$ what is $a_2$? Now, what about $a_3$? $a_4$? $a_5$?

Comment: $a_0 = -1   ...   a_2 = 2 + 3 + 3 ... a_3 = 2 + 3 + 3 + 3$... and so on

Comment: This book solution is $a_n = a_{n-1} + 3 = (2 + 3 * (n-2)) + 3 = 2 + 3(n-1)$, but I have no idea how they came to that conclusion from my steps in my previous comment.

Comment: $$a_1=2$$ $$a_2=2+3$$ $$a_3=2+3+3$$ $$a_4=2+3+3+3$$ $$a_5=2+3+3+3+3$$ $$\vdots$$ At each stage we're adding a certain number of $3$s to $2$. In particular, $$a_1=2+3\cdot 0$$ $$a_2=2+3\cdot 1$$ $$a_3=2+3\cdot 2$$ $$a_4=2+3\cdot 3$$ $$a_5=2+3\cdot 4$$ $$\vdots$$ Are you seeing it now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!  Sleeping helped as well.  I submitted my assignment, which took 8 hours...